# Dependent DLLs of referenced ClassLibrary not added to BIN of application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

There are so many questions posted about this issue. I believe i have read them all and still not having much luck. I have a VS2015 project where i can do all that i have described below without issue. Also note that the process i went through to move the applications and class libraries from 2015 to 2017 was to fully rebuild them in 2017. In any case, i created a new solution in 2017 with new application and class library to prove my issue.

1. I created a new library call **ClassLibrary** and a new asp.net web app called **WebApplication**.
2. In ClassLibrary i then **added a nuget** for testing (i have also tested this with a file reference to a 3rd party DLL). In this case i added the AjaxControlToolkit 18.1.0 for testing.
3. Then in WebApplication project i **reference ClassLibrary**

I would expect this simple solution and project referencing to copy the dependent DLLS of ClassLibrary to WebApplication project bin. It does not. Prior to moving to VS 2017 this would (and still does in VS 2015) copy the dependency DLL of ClassLibrary in WebApplication's BIN. In the VS2017 project i described above the AjaxControlToolkit is not copied to the BIN, i only see a ClassLibrary.dll but none of its dependencies.

I have tried to "use" the AjaxControlToolkit in the WebApplication project code as some of the posts suggest. This does not work as the assembly is not available in the project and i get build errors. I've modified the .csproj files in so many different ways based on suggestions i have found on Stack, nothing works.

Whats even more strange is that i see the DLL in the bin but not listed in the project References. Even though the DLL is in the bin i am unable to work with it.
[image]

What is going on? This is such a simple exercise of referencing and after spending two days on Google searching on this it seems crazy that so many have this issue. Why are these DLLs not flowing all the way to the parent application BIN???

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, why have you included the nullreferenceexception tag? I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Very old dll are (like from window 95) are not considered compatible with VS.  In one case I had to manually put dll into bin folder. Then use a 2nd vendor supplied wrapper dll to interface to window 95 dll.  I would look at old working project and compare dlls in bin folder with new project.

Comment: My project is throwing that error because the DLL is not present in the application bin, but i can remove it as to not confuse things...

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the input. These are not old DLLs. I can throw any new popular NuGet into my ClassLibrary project and although it gets copied to the BIN it does not appear in the WebApplication references.

Comment: It has to be.  Did you use Add Existing item and then browse to the dll?  Only when it is add to project will it get copied to bin folder.  The only time I had issue is with the old dll and I got a not compatible error.  It was a mess because the wrapper was different for XP and Win7 and the non compatible dll was also different in XP and Win7,

Comment: It is not supposed to, never did before.  We can't see any repro code or compile error, makes it hard to help you.  If that class library exposes any types from the dependent assemblies in its own metadata then the compiler *may* insist on knowing what that dependent assembly looks like in order to figure out which method overload is the correct one.  In which case it reminds you that you need to add a reference.  Easy to fix, just add the reference.  Might be a bit disconcerting for a nuget library, but not a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant i thought i outlined my steps pretty clearly. There is no code cause these a brand new solution and projects i am testing with, specifically testing the references and copying of DLLs as mentioned. Within ClassLibrary i'm doing a simple AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion x = new Accordion(); just to force VS to recognize that the DLL is being used. This gets me a copy of the DLL in the bin like this image shows, but nothing in my references. Obviously the errors i receive in the WebApplication project are missing reference errors - i though it would be redundant to include those...

Comment: @HansPassant could you clarify what you mean by "it's not supposed to"? I've always knows project references to pull in the DLLs referenced in the library. Are you suggesting that i now have to go through every project and try and figure out the dependencies of all the referenced classes and make sure i then reference the DLL and nuget in both places? I feel like i'm in the twilight zone, i'm literally sitting here looking at a 2015 project that pulls in all the depended DLLS of a referenced project and you suggesting that this has never been this way?

Comment: Your assumption that a reference to ajaxcontroltoolkit should be added to your main project is just not correct.  No version of VS ever did.  You are expected to *only* use the class(es) from ClassLibrary.  If you *also* try to use ajaxcontroltoolkit class in your main project then you must add the reference yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant First of all according to MS "Copies of dependent assemblies, XML document files, license files, resource files" will be added to the bin in a project reference scenario. Additionally i have a dlls in ClassLibrary that i referenced off my local drive (not a nuget) that has exactly the same issue of not copying into the referencing bin. What you suggesting is that i install the nuget on all projects using it - fine i can do that... But now you also suggesting that i have to add all references to dependent DLLs located anywhere on any referenced ClassLibraries?

Comment: That is not what I suggested at all.  No real idea how to explain it better. If you had provided repro code I could say *there*, that's the problem.  But you didn't, so good luck with it.  Add the reference to move on.

Comment: @HansPassant what code would you like to see? Seriously? These are totally blank projects. This has nothing to do with code and everything to do with the references in the solution. If you want to repo it, just follow the 3 step process that was outlined. I'm asking for help in the best way possible but it's increasingly difficult to find it here without wading through downtalk and disdain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my post i mentioned that these projects originally in VS2015 were then recreated in VS2017. This process converted the original **Web Site** projects to **Web Application** projects.

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx#Anchor_1), in a Web Site project when a ClassLibrary is referenced as a project reference *"Copies of dependent assemblies, XML document files, license files, resource files, and so on."* (this includes installed Nugets in the ClassLibrary) are copied to the project BIN. This is not the case with Web Applications. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) for the differences. Installing the NuGet wherever it is needed is required, it will not be inherited from child references as it is with Web Site projects.